# Calculate Break Time

Tags: javascript, python

Is there any simple way to implement the following conditons into a simple one.

```
usual_work_start = 9:00
usual_work_end = 17:45
lunch_break_start = 12:00
lunch_break_end = 13:00

And if i am doing overtime 
ot_break_start = 17:45
ot_break_end = 18:15

And i have to get the break time depending upon my work_start and work_end times.
some examples are listen below
1. if work_start = 9:00 and work_end = 21:00 then break_time should be lunch_break + overtime_break (90mins break).
2. if work_start = 9:00 and work_end = 12:00 then break_time should be 0(didn't take any break).
3. if work_start = 9:00 and work_end = 17:45 then break_time should be only lunch time (60mins).
```

And so many test depending upon the start and end time.

I have done one but its very long nested if and else. Any simple idea will be of great help.　Any language is okay but preferred one is javascript or python.

Link to Question code - https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/236011/getting-break-time-taken?noredirect=1#comment462162_236011

Comment: Sooo this is homework?

Comment: Can you please add your code to the question?

Comment: I have implemented one but its very long nested if and else so I am scared if I need to any changes I'll need to go back from beginning and try to understand everything. @works_as_coded

Comment: @DamchoThinley Just put it on there, better than nothing

Comment: Do you want an answer in Python, why is Python tagged?

Comment: Answer can be okay in any language. or may be just a syntax or an idea. @PacketLoss

Answer (score 0):

```
//eg: 9*60 ; minutes of a day till 9'o clock
day_in_minutes_at_start = 9*60;
expected_work_end = (17*60) + 45;
temp_break_end = "18:15";
temp_time = temp_break_end.split(":");
actual_work_end = parseInt(temp_time[0] * 60) + parseInt(temp_time[1]);
break_time = parseInt(actual_work_end) - parseInt(expected_work_end);
// break_time => Break time in minutes
```

Answer (score 0):

Calculating break time with respect of time spent on work irrespective of start and end time would be more flexible if office hours are not rigid and same for everyone. This can be implemented as:

```
    if workTime < 3hrs:
        breaktime = 0
    elseif workTime > 3hrs && workTime < 7hr 45min:
        breaktime = 1hr
    elseif worktime > 7hr 45min:
        breaktime = 1hr 30min
```